# objective c can only be called from main thread

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native

I am trying to call a delegate from a callback method that is used from javascript. But I am getting the error `"Can only be called from main thread"` when I execute the delegate from the callback and not when the event fires.

Note: the error is on the last line of code.

Here is what the code looks like

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(setBold) {

  if(_bold == NO)
  {
    _bold = YES;
  }
  else if (_bold == YES)
  {
    _bold = NO;
  }
  else{
    _bold = NO;
  }

  if(_textV!=nil)
  {
    _delCalled = YES;
    [self textViewDidChangeSelection:_textV];
  }

}



-(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
  _textV = textView;

  _selectedText = [textView.text substringWithRange:textView.selectedRange];
  _rangeStart = textView.selectedRange.location;
  _rangeEnd = textView.selectedRange.length;

  if(_delCalled == YES)
  {
    [self applyBold:textView];
    _delCalled = NO;
  }



  NSDictionary *event = @{
                          @"target": textView.reactTag,
                          @"highlights": @{
                              @"text": textView.text,
                              @"range": @(textView.selectedRange.length),
                              @"cursorPosition": @(textView.selectedRange.location),
                              @"eventType": @"textViewDidChangeSelection",
                              }
                          };
  [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendInputEventWithName:@"topChange" body:event];
}

-(void)applyBold:(UITextView *)textView
{
  NSMutableAttributedString *formatString;
  UIFont* boldFont;
  NSString *selectedText = _selectedText;


  _rangeStart -=1;


  if(_rangeEnd == 0)
  {
    _rangeEnd = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    _rangeStart +=1;
  }

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(_rangeStart, _rangeEnd);


  if (_bold==YES) {
   boldFont= [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
  }
  else{
    boldFont= [UIFont systemFontOfSize:textView.font.pointSize];
  }

  NSAttributedString *lem = textView.attributedText;

    NSMutableAttributedString *textViewText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:textView.attributedText];


  NSDictionary *boldAttr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:boldFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

  formatString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:selectedText attributes:boldAttr];

  if(![selectedText isEqual:@""] || ![selectedText isEqual:@" "])
  {
    [textViewText replaceCharactersInRange:range withAttributedString:formatString];

//this is where the error happens
      textView.attributedText = textViewText;



  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS, any method that updates the UI must be invoked on the main thread. The iOS UIKit is not thread safe. So, the solution is to put that code on the main thread, like this

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   textView.attributedText = textViewText;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the row generating the error in a dispatch_async with the main queue

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed it.